# Symfony 4: Prevent Doctrine Fixtures from being loaded in DEV-Environment

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4

If you want to prevent the database fixtures from being loaded *accidentally* in the wrong environment, the (probably) best way is to activate the `DoctrineFixturesBundle` only in certain environment(s).

Up to Symfony 3.4 this was done in `app/AppKernel.php`, as described at https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/best_practices/business-logic.html#data-fixtures

How can this be achieved in Symfony 4 (Symfony Flex), where bundles are being loaded automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Symfony 4, this can be configured in `config/bundles.php`, by editing the line

```
Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
```

See https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/best_practices/business-logic.html#data-fixtures

When you remove the `'dev' => true,` part, and then try to load the fixtures in DEV environment by running `php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --env=dev`, you will get:

> Error thrown while running command "'doctrine:fixtures:load' --env=dev". Message: "There are no commands defined in the "doctrine:fixtures" namespace.

However, loading them in TEST environment still works: `php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --env=test`

Comment: Not exactly the same problem but I doctrine:fixtures command was not working for me. Spent the entire night on this thing. Realised from your answer that I have to mention --env=test flag to make it work.